I'm trying to identify a bicycle I have
The bicycle has a logo on the front that I'm not familiar with and it says waterlanderson on the rear. It is a single speed but looks like a 10 speed frame

Welcome. There's a guide on asking such questions, have you seen it? https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Photos would help, please.  You can add some with [edit]    Google is completely unaware of the word "waterlandson"

Did you find Walter Anderson's bike?

I just may have here's a picture of the name on side and front emblem.

The picture didn't upload.
